# Caesar cipher with multiple values

Tags: python, list

I'm new to stack overflow.
I'm trying to create a Caesar cipher that can take multiple inputs for shifts. I have all my shifts stored in a list. The message the user is attempting to encrypt is also stored in a list like so:

```
["Hello this is what the message looks like.", "It is stored in a list like so.", "It is pretty neet."]
```

The shift amount must start over on the next "line". So if the last `e` in `like` is shifted by `4` in a shift sequence of

```
[1,2,3,4,5],
```

the `I` in `It` would be shifted by `1`. I tried using a for loop to to search for each letter then use ord() to obtain the UTF code then add the shift but that did not work.I suspect this is because my shift values are held in a list. How would I approach this problem?

***EDIT***I am reposing this topic because my previous topic was closed for being "duplicate". However, I don't think it is a duplicate topic. The linked topic involved a shift amount that will always be constant. My program requires a shift amount that various depending on what the user inputs. My program also has a list containing the shift values. I cannot use some operations because it is a list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Caesar Cipher with multiple shifts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43328131/caesar-cipher-with-multiple-shifts)

Comment: If you don't think it was a duplicate, then you should have edited your old question and gotten it reopened.

Comment: Sorry I will keep that in mind for future posts.

Comment: @Geoffry96 you should do your own homework.

Comment: This is called a [Vigenère cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher).